# Drools boolean comparison

Tags: drools

Why `false == (cancelationCode == 'C')` bahaves differently
from `(cancelationCode == 'C') == false`?

Is it bug in drools 6.5.0 or am I missing anything?

---

Here are the full story:

I'm using Drools DSL, and I have to implement a rule:

```
rule "my business rule"
    dialect "mvel"
    when
        There is a trade that
        - Supervised Trade
        ...
    then
        ...
end
```

I have these DSL definitions:

```
[when] Supervised Trade = 
    Customer Trade 
    AND NOT Canceled 

[when] Customer Trade = (recordTypeCode is equal to '910')
[when] Canceled = (cancellationCode is equal to 'C')

[when] is equal to = ==

[when] {var1}?(?<![\w'])\s*AND\s*(?![\w']){var2}? = {var1} && {var2}
[when] {var1}?(?<![\w'])\s*OR\s*(?![\w']){var2}? = {var1} || {var2}
[when] {var1}?(?<![\w'])\s*NOT\s*(?![\w']){var2}? = {var1} false == {var2}
```

The requirenments is to write reusable DSL statements in positive manner and have an ability to negate them.

Originally NOT was implemented as `!` and it was working for current scenario. But it was not working for cases like `buySellTypeCode in ('B', 'S')`, which is working with `false == statement` though.

Rule is not triggered for the input object when it DSL is evaluated to

```
$trade: Trade((recordTypeCode == '910') && false == (cancellationCode == 'C'))
```

and it is triggered for the same input object when DSL is evaluated to

```
$trade: Trade((recordTypeCode == '910') && (cancellationCode == 'C') == false)
```

Comment: Maybe it's because you have one L in the first `cancelationCode` but two in the second?

Comment: no it's just my typo, I put simplified expression here to open a discussion )

Comment: You'll have to show a complete example ([mcve]) that demonstrates the issue, and explain what "bahaves differently" means. What is the value of `cancelationCode` and what is the result of those comparisons? It's very likely that the problem is somewhere else in the code.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking its ='C'.

Comment: 'behaves differently' means that for the same input object one statement triggers the rule but another doesn't

Comment: See this: http://www.jbug.jp/trans/jboss-rules3.0.2/ja/html/ch01s03.html. I think the problem is related to  `First Order Logic (FOL)`

Comment: I went through documentation, could you explain what could be wrong with `First Order Logic (FOL)`?

Comment: First order logic ensures rules will only be matched when no other keywords are present. In this example, the rule turns the sprinkler off when the fire is extinguished:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_soa_platform/5/html-single/jboss_rules_5_reference_guide/index#First_Order_Logic

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic

Comment: As a long-time coder who just tapped on the link as i have never heard of drools before, my first thought in reading this question is why even have such a logic construction in the first place? It seems very redundant.

Comment: this is generated code, result of DSL processing. The goal is DSL to be human readable and concise. Generated code must work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really behaves differently as it is parsed differently with DRL6 lexer.
`org.drools.compiler.compiler.DrlExprParser.parse` takes these text snippets as is, but
`BaseDescr expr = parser.conditionalOrExpression();` reveals that ANTLR parser process those differently.

When I changed `false == (cancelationCode == 'C')` to `true ^ (cancelationCode == 'C')` I got an error: "Predicate 'true ^ cancellationCode == 'C'' must be a Boolean expression". This reveals root cause of the problem - ANTLR parser strips braces around single statements, this is why

```
false == cancelationCode == 'C' -> doesn't work as expected    
cancelationCode == 'C' == false -> works as expected
```

Iterestingly but braces are not stripped around complex statements, so both works as expected:

```
false == (true && cancelationCode == 'C')
(true && cancelationCode == 'C') == false
```

I would say this 'optimization' is a bug.